# How to center align logo on this particular header

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for an help with a little challenge (for me a big one): I need to center align the logo of this header ( https://mastercanapa.com/ ) on mobile version... I tried every solution found online, but nothing helped. Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your css or style tag:

```
@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .btLogoArea {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .btMenuVertical .btLogoArea .logo {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vitor! Your solution worked perfectly, you let me figured out why my code wasn't working!Have a nice day,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Normally mobile design visible when browser width lower then 768px, but in your website mobile design visible when browser width lower then 1200px. So just add below *CSS* in your style.css file.

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Try this i hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks